# Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel issue

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-application-insights

After updating `'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights'` from 2.4.0 to 2.5.1
and it installing implicitly following packages

```
1.'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept'
2.'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector'
3.'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector'
4.'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer'
5.'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel'
```

and error is coming on this line of code

```
 config.LoggerFactory = loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights("", filter.Filter);
```

Could not load type `'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.Channel.Implementation.SamplingPercentageEstimatorSettings'` from assembly `'Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel'`, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/727 - Seems like this issue.

Comment: Ok. Means when 2.6.0 package releases this issue will be solve.

Comment: i am updated my  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights  to new version 2.6.1 and all other nuget packages also which are mention above but still issue is persist.

Comment: It was expected to be fixed with 2.6.1 but looks like the required change did not make it to 2.6.1. I'd expect a 2.6.2 release very soon to include this.

Comment: This was fixed in 2.6.4 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.6.4